# Is it possible to put an xcodeprojfile in the same dir as the Makefile for an External Build Target?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I need to put the xcodeprojfile in the same dir as the Makefile for my External Build Target without using an absolute path for the Directory location. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer is yes!
First, copy your .xcodeproj file into the same directory as your makefile.
Then add a reference to your makefile to the project (make sure if you have a makefile.in and a makefile, that the makefile.in is above the makefile in the list of project items.) 
Then you need to set the external build source directory to . where the . represents the current directory.
My project builds just fine!